# Какой вид синтаксической связи используется для пояснительных определений?

Tags: грамматика

1) **Обособленное определение**

Я смотрел на **залитый** лунным светом **пруд**.  Причастие согласуется с существительным в роде, числе и падеже. Я смотрел на **пруд, залитый** лунным светом. **Согласование осталось.** (Полупредикативную связь всего оборота с предложением не рассматриваем).

Таким образом, обособленные определения **сохраняют синтаксическую связь с определяемым словом.**

2) **Обособленное пояснительное определение (раскрывает содержание местоименного определения)**

(1) **Другая, железная**, лестница висела в воздухе, как подвесной мост. (2) На ней уже было **другое** платье, **очень простое и очень ловкое.** (3) **Такие** записки, **для одного себя**, часто бывают нелогичными и непоследовательными.

**Вопросы:**

**Какой вид синтаксической связи** используется для пояснительных определений (с определяемым словом, а также  м**ежду основным и поясняющим определением**)?

Пояснительные определения **сохраняют синтаксическую связь**  с предложением или словами в предложении?

Answer (score 1):

Синтаксические связи в предложении  делятся на  предикативные и непредикативные.
Предикативные связи  - координация, соположение,тяготение.

Непредикативные связи: 1) пояснительная; 2) двунаправленная; 3) детерминантная; 4) присоединительная, 5) сочинительная.

Распопов в «Строении простого предложения» называет эту связь аппликацией, в «Грамматике-80» отмечено, что пояснительная связь характеризуется как разновидность сочинительной связи (§ 2084).

Пояснительная связь – это связь словоформ, при которой второй компонент как бы «накладывается» на первый и благодаря этому уподобляется ему в синтаксических отношениях с другими компонентами предложения. Пояснительная связь раскрывает собственно пояснительные синтаксические отношения, выражающие разные названия одного и того же явления. Пояснительную связь можно усмотреть в случаях, которые обычно трактуются как обособление приложений,уточнений, пояснений (с включением не только приименных, но и приадъективных, принаречных компонентов).

*Ухаживала за мной одна девушка, полька.* Обособленное приложение полька уподобляется словоформе девушка, как бы накладываясь на нее.

Ср.: *Она выходила на улицу в стареньком, очень потрепанном, платье. Налево, у дороги, стояло одинокое дерево.*

https://studopedia.su/10_137276_sintaksis-vidi-sintaksicheskih-svyazey-slovosochetanie-predlozhenie.html

Говорить о согласовании  **пруд залитый** в предложении *Я смотрел на **пруд, залитый** лунным светом*  некорректно, т.к. согласование, управление, примыкание - виды подчинительной связи  в словосочетании, а сочетание словоформы с обособленным оборотом не является словосочетанием.

```
      Пояснительные определения сохраняют синтаксическую связь 
      с предложением или словами в предложении?
```

Пояснительные определения связаны с поясняемым словом пояснительной связью:

(1) *Другая, железная, лестница висела в воздухе, как подвесной мост.*

Определения **другая и железная**  связаны между собой пояснительной связью.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но непонятного много. 1) «…на пруд, залитый лунным светом». Связь полупредикативная  с  точки зрения семантики (есть второй смысловой центр: пруд был залит), присловным распространителем оборот не является, словосочетания не образует, но РЕАЛЬНОЕ СОГЛАСОВАНИЕ в роде, числе и падеже остается. Поэтому есть мнение, что важной особенностью обособленных членов являются ДВОЙНЫЕ синтаксические связи: образуется новая связь, но и формальная связь остается. И я не понимаю, почему некорректно говорить об этой связи.

Comment: 2) Все мы знаем о сочинительной и подчинительной связи. Сочинительная связь ― это связь однородных членов, причем однородных грамматически и семантически. Но явно просматриваются грамматически однородные, но семантически неоднородные отношения: ПОЯСНЕНИЕ, УТОЧНЕНИЕ. Было бы логично считать их РАЗНОВИДНОСТЬЮ сочинительной связи (с аппликацией членов, с другой интонацией).  Присоединительные члены ― это тоже (1) пояснение, уточнение или (2) предикативное обособление, но с другой (присоединительной) интонацией.

Comment: 3) Во фразе «пояснительные определения связаны пояснительной связью» я не вижу нового содержания, пока нет определения этой связи. Я бы определила пояснение как НЕОДНОРОДНУЮ СОЧИНИТЕЛЬНУЮ СВЯЗЬ. Какой смысл в том, чтобы придумывать новые термины, если по сути они являются разновидностью базовых понятий. Грамматика должна быть ясной даже ребенку, а у нас она и студентам не очень ясна.

Comment: @Jasmin,  а что за новая связь, о который вы пишете в своем комментарии?

Comment: Я имела в виду, что предикативная (новая) связь образуется  именно при обособлении, без обособления была только грамматическая связь согласование.

Comment: Jasmin, что ж тут непонятного? Вы спрашивали о синтаксических связях, а это только предикативные, непредикативные, полупредикативные, но тут же сказали, что "полупредикативную связь всего оборота с предложением не рассматриваем", а вопрос о связи слов пруд и залитый Вас всё-таки интересует - это как? Выдернули слова из разных синтагм - и это корректно? Вы говорите не о синтаксических связях, а о семантических. Если по Вашему примеру студенты начнут устанавливать такие синтаксические  связи при разборе - им поставят неуд за неразграничение сочетаний и предложений.

Comment: Во фразе «пояснительные определения связаны пояснительной связью» нет никакого нового содержания,школьники знают, что такое пояснение,и пояснительная связь им тоже будет понятна. Кстати, в школьном разборе этого вообще нет, там просто говорят, чем осложнено предложение.А вот если школьникам будут говорить об однородном сочинении и неоднородном - они Вам спасибо скажут. Хорошо, что видят однородное и неоднородное подчинение в СПП. А в науке есть такие термины, это не Ваше изобретение, каждый учёный вводит свои термины.В грамматике-80 есть: пояснительный оборот - аппликация - сочинительная связь